# Update an column after desired amount of minutes

Tags: mysql, intervals

I want to update an column after every 20 minutes but it wont not work as I will. I use this SQL:

```
UPDATE visitors SET
is_online = '0'
WHERE is_online = '1'
AND DATE_ADD(date_lastactive, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) < NOW()
```

The database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `page` text NOT NULL,
  `page_get` text NOT NULL,
  `date_visited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_lastactive` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_revisited` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

I have tried to change the `<` to `>` but it updates after every page refreshes with that arrow.

How can I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want sql query for updating column by checking difference of 20 minutes?

Comment: No. After every 20 minutes it will update the database.

Comment: Ok. But if I choose to have `>` it will only update the database after every page refresh :S

Comment: it's impossible what you want to do

Comment: Is it impossible when I have done it before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run this query every 20 minutes independently on your site visitors and page loads you have to use a system scheduler: cron on Unix, and Task Scheduler on Windows.
Just code a simple shell script.

Comment: Much true but I want to use this SQL question for now.

Comment: @ErikEdgren: I meant exactly SQL. If you use Unix your script willl look like a command:
mysql -u your_user -pyour_password -e "your_query" your_yourdatabase

Comment: Okej. I haven't learn anything about that sort of programming yet :P Thanks! I will use that shell script sometimes in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not make an sql query that repeats itself in every 20 minutes. There is no such of combination of mysql statements.

Comment: Hm. Okej. I have used that SQL question on other websites few years ago and they worked perfectly

Comment: I don't think so, it was never possible scheduling operations in mysql from query.

Comment: Scheduler? Oh no! :P I want it to update when someone visit the website

Comment: then you didn't specify it very clear. So you want to check the users status to offline if he doesnt make anything in 20 minutes?

Comment: Yes I can. I have done it before but that was few years ago. I think I have the solution in some old projects though. Didn't think about that until now